Calling next message handler from parent class
I have the following setup.
class A : DelegatingHandler{
     protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
           HttpRequestMessage request,
           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
          // some logic.
          return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     }
}

class B : A{
     protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
           HttpRequestMessage request,
           CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
          // some logic.
          if(condition == true){
              **// call next handler. skip A's logic. How to achieve this?**
          }
          else{
               return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
          }
           
     }
}

How can directly call next message handler without going through A's logic? Any help would be appreciated.

Do you have to dervice from A, could you derive from DelegatingHandler?
